# Is it possible to create a popup that open automatically after 10 sec of delay

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a popup  that shows after 10 sec delay after customer land of product page and if they click outside popup should get closed

Here is my html and css. Can you help me with the JS?

```css
  css -.overlay_flight_traveldil {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

.overlay_flight_traveldil:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 100;
  z-index: 5;
}

.popup_flight_travlDil {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 5;
}

.popup_flight_travlDil .close_flight_travelDl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 20px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

.popup_flight_travlDil .content_flightht_travel_dil {
  max-height: 60%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .popup_flight_travlDil {
    width: 33%;
    z-index: 5;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .popup_flight_travlDil {
    width: 90%;
    z-index: 5;
  }
```

```html
<div id="popup_flight_travlDil3" class="overlay_flight_traveldil">
  <div class="popup_flight_travlDil">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0605/0680/0349/files/Mcaffeine-5.jpg?v=1664169142" alt="gh" width="100%" height="80%" />
    <a class="close_flight_travelDl" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content_flightht_travel_dil">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you creating/showing this popup to begin with? JS has [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) which is probably what you're after.

Comment: I want to answer you but you really confused me. in your question you said show it after 10 second then user close it when click outside. then in others comments, you said it's not going back to previous page. and in your HTML code, the X close button is a link with # in it, so it will go to the top of the page. WHAT EXACTLY DO YOU WANT?

Comment: I am sry that you got confused but i found my thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the div hidden

Then check what is clicked

I changed the X to a button since there is no need to make it a link. It is not going anywhere. And your framework registers it as a navigation so the back button is affected

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const pop = document.getElementById("popup_flight_travlDil3");
  setTimeout(() => pop.hidden = false, 1000); // show after 1 second - change to 10000 to get 10 secs
  document.addEventListener("click", (e) => { // what did you click?
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.matches(".close_flight_travelDl") || // the close button 
      !e.target.closest(".popup_flight_travlDil")) { // or something else not the advert
      pop.hidden = true;
    }
  })
})
```

```css
  css -.overlay_flight_traveldil {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

.overlay_flight_traveldil:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 100;
  z-index: 5;
}

.popup_flight_travlDil {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 5;
}

.popup_flight_travlDil .close_flight_travelDl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 20px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
}

.popup_flight_travlDil .content_flightht_travel_dil {
  max-height: 60%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .popup_flight_travlDil {
    width: 33%;
    z-index: 5;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .popup_flight_travlDil {
    width: 90%;
    z-index: 5;
  }
```

```html
<div id="popup_flight_travlDil3" class="overlay_flight_traveldil" hidden>
  <div class="popup_flight_travlDil">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0605/0680/0349/files/Mcaffeine-5.jpg?v=1664169142" alt="gh" width="100%" height="80%" />
    <button type="button" class="close_flight_travelDl">&times;</button>
    <div class="content_flightht_travel_dil">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello I tried code  same issue if user click back they must go prev page  but its not ? could please check again

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by going to previous page. There is NO navigation in my script at all

Comment: i complete understand but suppose you visit my site and look popup you cancel that now you want to go back prev page ( as this popup will on product page) then you click back but inside you get stuck on same and have click 2 times for going back that is what problem with this script

Comment: "inside you get stuck" ??  I cannot imagine that happening. You can click the back button just fine with this script. There is nothing that stops you from clicking back. Did you try this script? And did this script block you from clicking back, or perhaps you have another script on the same page that does that.

Comment: yes wait ill share with you test devloped link

Comment: https://s3q0zmzzi53qbvh0-60506800349.shopifypreview.com here link go inside borosil and click on any product? see popup close and try to get back?

Comment: In Chrome no problem at all. You have a HUGE amount of console errors though

Comment: did you really check ? because as I can see there is problem going back after product page ! and console i tried couldn't figure out

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/dxOpAwo

Comment: I see  you missed 1 step i.e cancel the popup and then try back button!

Comment: You need to change the link to a button as I suggested. Your framework registers the click on a link as navigation. Look at my code and the CSS and use a button

Comment: not working anymore can you check and send whole code in format that would be helpful?

Comment: It is complete above. You need to ALSO change the CSS: `.popup_flight_travlDil .close_flight_travelDl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 20px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

setting timeout for 10 seconds & adding class of `.popup` which is defined in css with `visiblity:visible` & `opacity:1` & adding click event on close Button and if user clicks it removes the `.popup` class making it hidden again

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector(".overlay_flight_traveldil").classList.add("popup");
}, 10000);

let closebtn = document.querySelector(".close_flight_travelDl");

closebtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {

  document.querySelector(".overlay_flight_traveldil").classList.remove("popup");

})
```

```css
  .overlay_flight_traveldil {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  animation: popup 2s 1;
}

.popup {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1
}

.overlay_flight_traveldil:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 100;
  z-index: 5;
}

.popup_flight_travlDil {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 5;
}

.popup_flight_travlDil .close_flight_travelDl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 20px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

.popup_flight_travlDil .content_flightht_travel_dil {
  max-height: 60%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .popup_flight_travlDil {
    width: 33%;
    z-index: 5;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .popup_flight_travlDil {
    width: 90%;
    z-index: 5;
  }
```

```html
<div id="popup_flight_travlDil3" class="overlay_flight_traveldil">
  <div class="popup_flight_travlDil">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0605/0680/0349/files/Mcaffeine-5.jpg?v=1664169142" alt="gh" width="100%" height="80%" />
    <a class="close_flight_travelDl" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content_flightht_travel_dil">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi Umair thanks for help but this code hide only it does not take user back to prev page after clicking back

Comment: Also this code does not close the popup if you click outside it

Answer (score -1):

You can do that just by making the popup invisible by adding the following lines

```css
 .popup_flight_travlDil {
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
}
```

And then, you would need some JavaScript to make the popup visible after 10 seconds. For that,

```js
const showPopup = () => {
  const popup = document.getElementsByClassName("popup_flight_travlDil")[0];
  popup.style.opacity = 1;
  popup.style.visibility = "visible";
};

setTimeout(showPopup, 10000);
```

Here, the function `showPopup` finds the `div` that was made invisible by using CSS, and then makes it visible. Whereas, the line  `setTimeout(showPopup, 10000);` calls the `showPopup` function after 10 seconds. Note that the `setTimeout` function takes 2 parameters, the function to call and time interval(in milliseconds) to wait before calling that function.

Comment: thanks for your help but with his if user click  back they will on same  page  i want them to redirect back as well

Comment: can you tell me more about it? Where do you want the user to be redirected? and also where should the user click to be redirected?